# How to control number of parquet files generated when using partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` that I need to write to S3 according to a specific partitioning. The code looks like this:

```
dataframe
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "date", "country", "predicate")
  .parquet(outputPath)
```

The `partitionBy` split the data into a fairly large number of folders (~400) with just a little bit of data (~1GB) in each. And here comes the problem -  because the default value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is 200, the 1GB of data in each folder is split into 200 small parquet files, resulting in roughly 80000 parquet files being written in total. This is not optimal for a number of reasons and I would like to avoid this.

I can of course set the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to a much smaller number, say 10, but as I understand this setting also controls the number of partitions for shuffles in joins and aggregation, so I don't really want to change this.

Does anyone know if there is another way to control how many files are written?

Comment: Have you tried repartitioning the dataframe before `.write`? At first glance it seems `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is only used in shuffles and joins, but nowhere else. Otherwise you should open a ticket for an additional `numParameter` param in partitionBy.

Comment: @MariusSoutier Hmmm... I would think that calling `repartition` _before_ `write` would cause my original `dataframe` to be repartitioned before it's then repartitioned by the `partitionBy` function. Repartitioning the original dataframe into just 10 partitions would most definitely lead to an OOM exception.  However, I have just started the job to test it. I will get back with an update as soon as it completes.

Comment: @MariusSoutier it works! Fantastic. Thank you! Do you want to post it as a reply - then I will mark it as answered :-)

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt i have a similar issue but sort of reversed. I use a code similar to yours to create partitions based on two columns. But i end up with 7-15 files each ranging between 30-70MB in size. But I want to increase the number of files in each partition, and keep the maximum size of each file to around 15MB. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @swordfish hmm, well - maybe you could use the `SizeEstimator` to estimate the size of your `dataframe` and then repartition it into the number of partitions that will generate files around 15MB? Note that the `SizeEstimater` will give you an estimate of the size in memory, so depending on how you store it the dataframe, you have to work out how size in memory maps to size on disk...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you noted correctly, `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` only applies to shuffles and joins in SparkSQL.

`partitionBy` in `DataFrameWriter` (you move 
from `DataFrame` to `DataFrameWriter` as soon as you call `write`) simply operates on the previous number of partitions. (The writer's `partitionBy` only assigns columns to the table / parquet file that will be written out, so it has nothing to do with the number of partitions. This is a bit confusing.)

Long story short, just `repartition` the `DataFrame` before you transform it to a writer.